# Linking each item group of a Foreign Key reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-orm, django-tables2

I am trying to set up a reverse lookup for Lesson objects off of Unit objects.

Here's the Lesson object:

```
class Lesson(CreatorModel):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=128)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='lessons')
```

So I can do a reverse lookup off a unit object with `unit.lessons`

I am trying to get a comma separated list of Lesson objects in my Unit List table. Here's the column that I've tried, that doesn't work:

```
lessons = tables.Column(linkify=lambda record: record.lessons.all())
```

It only shows me wrongly linked queryset objects: `[<Lesson: Test Lesson>]`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`tables.ManyToManyColumn`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#manytomanycolumn) like this:

```
class Unit(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=128)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # make sure you define this method on Unit.
        return reverse('TODO', args=[self.pk])

class Lesson(CreatorModel):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=128)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='lessons')


class UnitTable(tables.Table
    lessons = tables.ManyToManyColumn(linkify_item=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I think that got me a step closer. The items look right but the links are not formatted properly. It is all one big link and they're not using the `get_absolute_url` of the Lesson, they're linked to the `get_absolute_url` of the Unit instead. 

Thanks again Jieter!

Comment: Would you like me to post all the info into Github for you? Let me know what I can do to help you out! Thanks!